# Negative Boost in Solr

Tags: sorting, solr

I have a 'charges' field in my index . I want to boost results whose charges value is not equal to 0 . I tried using the bq parameter for this , but it did not work out .

```
&bq=charges:"0"^-1
```

I tried using the above , however I got a 400 error report .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @harmstyler
Instead of Boosting negatively, you can boost the the no zero values positively (if charges is an integer field) e.g.

```
bq=charges:[1 TO *]^10
```

Answer (score 7):

This is old post but not quite updated, Negative boost is currently supported.

Below from [Solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Usingnegativeboost)  on negative boost:

> Negative query boosts have been supported at the "Query" object level for a long time (resulting in negative scores for matching documents). Now the QueryParsers have been updated to handle this too.

Part `resulting in negative scores for matching documents` might not always be true, as explained below.

Example usage: Considering your collection name is `product_collection` and you want to bury(negative boost) product with specific brand:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/product_collection/select?q=shoes&bq=brand:puma^-2&defType=dismax
```

This query will be parsed to:

```
"parsedquery_toString": "+((keyword:shoes)^1.0) () (brand:puma)^-2.0"
```

In this case, `-2` factor will be multiplied to tf-idf score of `(brand:puma)` match, resulting in lower score for documents containing `brand puma`.

But, adding negative factor in boost query does not mean, it will always produce negative final score for document. For instance, if documents tf-idf score for `keyword:shoes` match is `3.0` and tf-idf score of `brand:puma` results in `-1.5`, still the overall result will be 1.5(positive). So, **use negative boost factor accordingly**.

One such example from my own collection:

> "\n3.4329534 = sum of:\n  **6.151505 = weight(keyword:shoes in 5786)** [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    6.151505 = score(doc=5786,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n      4.2804184 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        199.0 = docFreq\n        14417.0 = docCount\n      1.437127 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n        1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        7.7978773 = avgFieldLength\n        2.0 = fieldLength\n  **-2.7185516 = weight(brand:puma in 5786)** [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    -2.7185516 = score(doc=5786,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n      -2.0 = boost\n      1.3592758 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        3704.0 = docFreq\n        14422.0 = docCount\n      1.0 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1) from:\n        1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.0 = parameter b (norms omitted for field)\n",

Score of keyword:shoes = 6.151505

Score of brand:puma = -2.7185516

Resulting in overall score positive score of 3.4329534

Comment: Could you add a proper example to your answer, as well as include the relevant text from the documentation?

Comment: Not sure from which version negative boosting is supported but bq=charges:"0"^-10.0 will bury the product to the end of the resultset from solr version 6.6 and above. If this does not work, then you might want to increase the negative boost.

Comment: Sadly, with Solr 8 negative boosts stopped to work even though the documentation is unchanged. Now the result is "boost must be a positive float, got -10.0"

Answer (score 5):

Negative boosts are not supported by Solr. However, with that said, you can boost your content with a very low number to give it the effect of having a negative boost. Remember `^1` is considered the default boost. So, `&bq=charges:"0"^1` is the same as `&bq=charges:"0"`.
If you want to create a 'negative boost' try `&bq=charges:"0"^0.8`. For full documentation [view this article](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F).

Comment: I had tried adding a negative boost using figures like : 0.00001 . However it did not yield exact results on my data set . So , I accepted Jayendra's answer .

Comment: This answer is not correct. Even 0.0001 is a boost but a very small boost: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F